# How can I repeat last substitution and with the same flags

Tags: substitute

`&` repeats the last `:s`

But it doesn't repeat with flags, e.g. a global sub:

```
:s/"/'/g
```

won't replace in the same way on consecutive lines with `&`, running `:s/"/'/g` on the first line here and then `&` on the second

```
["first", "second"]
["third", "fourth"]
```

produces

```
['first', 'second']
['third", "fourth"]
```

the global option has been forgotten about when using `&` on the second line

How can I quickly repeat last substitute command *with* flags?

(*not*  `@:` because I may have other commands run after `:s`)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is exactly what `:&&` does:

```
                            *:&&*
[&] Must be the first one: Keep the flags from the previous substitute
    command.  Examples: >
        :&&
        :s/this/that/&
<   Note that `:s` and `:&` don't keep the flags.
```

There are also the `&` and `g&` commands:

```
                                *&*
&           Synonym for `:s` (repeat last substitute).  Note
            that the flags are not remembered, thus it might
            actually work differently.  You can use `:&&` to keep
            the flags.

                                *g&*
g&          Synonym for `:%s//~/&` (repeat last substitute with
            last search pattern on all lines with the same flags).
            For example, when you first do a substitution with
            `:s/pattern/repl/flags` and then `/search` for
            something else, `g&` will do `:%s/search/repl/flags`.
            Mnemonic: global substitute.
```

And you could map `&` to be more like `:&&`:

```
nnoremap & :&&<CR>
xnoremap & :&&<CR>
```

Comment: Remember that if you already accidentally pressed &, it becomes the last substitution and the flags are gone

Comment: This is correct, but if you add more info the answer will be better. I propose to guide the reader to the relevant help sections, where this is explained immediately. E.g. `:help :&`. This may also guide readers to learn about things like the mappings `&` and `g&`.

Comment: I also think that the answers should be full sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a range operation for substitutions.  From the example:

```
["first", "second"]
["third", "fourth"]
```

Replacing `"` with `'`, while cursor is on first line:

`:.,+1s/"/'/g`

Or from start of file to end of file:

`:1,$s/"/'/g`

`.` = current line of file, `$` = last line of file, `+x` = delta line (positive offset), `-x` = delta line (negative offset), `g` = globally (all occurrences on line)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I think by "context" you mean a range (`:help [range]`)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggested.  I changed the post

Comment: Pro-tip: `%` is the same range as `1,$` :)